Shorten traveller prayer in home country or not
I am travelling back to home country for 4 days. Once there, shall I shorten prayer or pray full?

assalam alaikom it depend i will share the link of 2 video they are in you situation and scholars give them a response https://islamicfiqh.net/en/videos/can-expats-or-people-residing-abroad-shorten-prayers-when-visiting-their-hometown-2671 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HCzHIvDOvU
